# In JavaScript, where do prototype's functions hide when we instantiate the derived object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I am currently trying to figure out exactly how the prototypical inheritance works in JavaScript. Here is the mystery I currently trying to solve.

Suppose we set up the following structure:

```
var base = { greet : "hello" }

var child = function () {}

child.prototype = base;
child.prototype.protoSomething = function () {}

var instance = new child();
```

Nothing fancy. Now lets see what `instance` has for properties (own or otherwise):

```
for(prop in instance) {
    console.log(prop); // prints 'greet', 'protoSomething'
}
```

Alright, so it has `greet` and `protoSomething`, are they `instance`'s own members?

```
for(prop in instance) {
    if(instance.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        console.log(prop); // nothing is printed
}
```

Nope, own property list is empty. Are they in `instance`'s prototype?

```
if(instance.prototype === undefined) {
    console.log("'instance' has no prototype"); // gets printed
}
```

Well, bummer, `instance` doesn't have a prototype assigned. So, if the properties are not *own* and there is no prototype, where are they coming from? I feel like some sort of a diagram would be very nice at this point.

Comment: Keep in mind that all properties are not marked as enumerable and thus all properties won't necessarily show with a `for (prop in instance)` iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a function has the property  `prototype`.

```
instance.constructor.prototype === base // return true
```

To get a prototype of an object, you should use the [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf) method.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(instance) === base // return true
```

Comment: hmm... `child` is a function object, and I naively thought that instantiating it would result in another function object. But even if I checked, i still didn't know about Object.getPrototypeOf (never seen code that used it). Thanks.

Comment: @xdazz, why did it create a Object instead of Function? `child` is a function and that's what I instantiated.

Comment: because you use new to create an object.

Comment: interesting, since everything is an object, I just assumed that when docs said `new` creates an object instance, it would be of the same kind as the source. Guess it's true what they say, assumption is the mother of all screw ups.

Answer (score 1):

This page should help you out:

http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

In short, the 'behind the scenes' prototype of an instance (created via `new`) is not accessible in any way, hence why it returns `undefined`. Only the constructor (on which you've manually set a `.prototype` property) will return anything when you try to retrieve it.